# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{\left[\frac{\ln\left(1+2^x\right)}{\ln\left(1+3^x\right)}\right]}$

Tags: limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

> Find without using derivatives the following limit $$\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{\left[\frac{\ln\left(1+2^x\right)}{\ln\left(1+3^x\right)}\right]}$$

I have no idea what to do! I have tried squeezing it, using substitutions, but it is untouchable! Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one is in a squeezing mood, let our function be $f(x)$. For positive $x$ we have
$$\frac{\ln(2^x)}{\ln(3^x+3^x)}\lt f(x)\lt \frac{\ln(2^x+2^x)}{\ln(3^x)}.$$

Comment: In my opinion, the answer by Harish Chandra Rajpoot is more useful.

Answer (score 11):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+2^x)}{\ln(1+3^x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln2^x(1+2^{-x})}{\ln3^x(1+3^{-x})}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln2^x+\ln(1+2^{-x})}{\ln3^x+\ln(1+3^{-x})}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x\ln2+\ln(1+2^{-x})}{x\ln3+\ln(1+3^{-x})}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln2+\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+2^{-x})}{\ln3+\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+3^{-x})}$$
$$=\frac{\ln2+0}{\ln3+0}=\color{red}{\frac{\ln2}{\ln3}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't thought to take out the largest exponential of x...

Answer (score 3):

The number $1$ is negligible faces to $2^x$ and $3^x$ as $x$ tends to infinity so

$$\ln(1+2^x)\sim \ln(2^x)=x\ln2$$
and similarly for the denominator so we find the limit $\frac{\ln2}{\ln3}$.

Comment: We cannot use approximations, we haven't "officially" learnt them yet!!! Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I think you should know that $1+y \approx y$ if $y>>1$